# Prevent Images From Overlapping Border From a Table?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am currently testing out how to create a newsletter. I have made a template. I am also very new to designing. I have made a table of album releases however, it is not fitting within the border I created. How can I fix this?

I have added the code here.

Also, I want to note that I am adding the CSS into the html so a specific newsletter website can accept the newsletter. Although I was taught the other way where I create both a separate html and css file, this is how it has to be for now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NewsLetter Template</title>
  <style type="text/css" >
  body {
    border: 5px solid #ffff;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px auto;

  }
  .img1 {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative
  } 

  .img2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative
  }

  h2 { 
    background-color: red;
    text-align:"center";
    font-family: Helvetica; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
  }

  .performance {
    width: 250px;
  }

  p {
     font-family: Helvetica; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: black;

  }

  .performancetype {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica; 

  }

  h3 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 500;  
  }

  table {
    display:inline-block;
     width:"100%"; 
   
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->

     
    <div style="min-height: 100vh; position: relative; border: 5px red solid; text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img class="img1" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt="Sample"/></a>

      <div>

<!-- Icons -->
        <tr> 
        <td align="center">
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt=" Facebook" border="0"/>
          </a>
          
      
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt=" Twitter"border="0"/>
          </a> 
      
        
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt="YouTube" border="0"/>
          </a>
        </td>         
      </tr>

    </div>

  <br></br>

<div>
  <h2>Check Out New Releases In The Following Categories</h2>
</div>

<!-- NEW RELEASE CATEGORIES -->


<!-- BEGIN UPCOMING INSTORE//-->
<h2>Upcoming Instore Events</h2>

<!-- BEGIN IN STORE -->


<!-- PERFORMER IMAGE -->


<div>
  <h2> Breakout Specials & Releases </h2>
</div>

<table>

  <tr>   
                   
                  
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/Lovely250-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER LP" title="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER LP" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP">LOVELYTHEBAND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP">FINDING IT PREORDER LP</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] PREORDER FOR EVENT WRISTBAND</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/Lovely250-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER CD" title="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER CD" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD">LOVELYTHEBAND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD">FINDING IT PREORDER CD</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] PREORDER FOR EVENT WRISTBAND</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/beatles-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="BEATLES - YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)" title="BEATLES - YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039">BEATLES</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039">YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] Limited edition 7-inch vinyl picture disc now available!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>

          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0619/clutch-250x250.JPG" 
            alt="CLUTCH - HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)" title="CLUTCH - HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842">CLUTCH</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842">HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] Picture disc now available!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
              
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/devil-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="DEVILDRIVER - OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1" title="DEVILDRIVER - OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126">DEVILDRIVER</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126">OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/townsend-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="DEVIN TOWNSEND - OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV" title="DEVIN TOWNSEND - OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026">DEVIN TOWNSEND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026">OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>

     </tr>

      <tr>   
         <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/goldfrapp-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="GOLDFRAPP - SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)" title="GOLDFRAPP - SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523">GOLDFRAPP</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523">SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/immortal-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)" title="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225">IMMORTAL</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225">NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Indie exclusive black and white colored vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
               
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/immortal-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS" title="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021">IMMORTAL</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021">NORTHERN CHAOS GODS</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/marr-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="JOHNNY MARR - CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)" title="JOHNNY MARR - CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600">JOHNNY MARR</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600">CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Indie exclusive purple vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/lucifer-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LUCIFER - LUCIFER II" title="LUCIFER - LUCIFER II" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728">LUCIFER</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728">LUCIFER II</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/perfect-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="PERFECT CIRCLE - EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)" title="PERFECT CIRCLE - EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102">PERFECT CIRCLE</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102">EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Red and blue vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/murphy-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="PETER MURPHY - 5 ALBUMS" title="PETER MURPHY - 5 ALBUMS" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523">PETER MURPHY</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523">5 ALBUMS</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/tiger-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="TIGER ARMY - DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)" title="TIGER ARMY - DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558">TIGER ARMY</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558">DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   

      
      
   </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

When you run it, the new releases look like this

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdM95.jpg)

What should I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Let the images have dynamic sizing:

```
.img-responsive{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

They'll fill the `<td>`'s width 100% (and no more) and the height will be dynamically sized to retain the original aspect ratio. This is useful for rectangular images such as the Yellow Submarine album in your example.

Comment: @ayewassup You'd just add that in anywhere at the top between the `<style>` tags. Your images already have the class `img-responsive` assigned to them per your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Apply `width: 100%` to those images which are inside table cells. This will fit them exactly into the table cells, no matter how large they are:

```css
td img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NewsLetter Template</title>
  <style type="text/css" >
  body {
    border: 5px solid #ffff;
    max-width: 700px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 20px auto;

  }
  .img1 {
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    position: relative
  } 

  .img2 {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative
  }

  h2 { 
    background-color: red;
    text-align:"center";
    font-family: Helvetica; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
  }

  .performance {
    width: 250px;
  }

  p {
     font-family: Helvetica; 
    font-size: 20px; 
    color: black;

  }

  .performancetype {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Helvetica; 

  }

  h3 {
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 500;  
  }

  table {
    display:inline-block;
     width:"100%"; 
   
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->

     
    <div style="min-height: 100vh; position: relative; border: 5px red solid; text-align: center;">
        <a href="http://www.google.com">
        <img class="img1" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt="Sample"/></a>

      <div>

<!-- Icons -->
        <tr> 
        <td align="center">
          <a href="http://www.google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt=" Facebook" border="0"/>
          </a>
          
      
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt=" Twitter"border="0"/>
          </a> 
      
        
          <a href="http://google.com">
            <img class="img2" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/003/338/320px--Insert_image_here-.svg.png" alt="YouTube" border="0"/>
          </a>
        </td>         
      </tr>

    </div>

  <br></br>

<div>
  <h2>Check Out New Releases In The Following Categories</h2>
</div>

<!-- NEW RELEASE CATEGORIES -->


<!-- BEGIN UPCOMING INSTORE//-->
<h2>Upcoming Instore Events</h2>

<!-- BEGIN IN STORE -->


<!-- PERFORMER IMAGE -->


<div>
  <h2> Breakout Specials & Releases </h2>
</div>

<table>

  <tr>   
                   
                  
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/Lovely250-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER LP" title="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER LP" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP">LOVELYTHEBAND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYLP">FINDING IT PREORDER LP</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] PREORDER FOR EVENT WRISTBAND</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/Lovely250-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER CD" title="LOVELYTHEBAND - FINDING IT PREORDER CD" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD">LOVELYTHEBAND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/LOVELYCD">FINDING IT PREORDER CD</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] PREORDER FOR EVENT WRISTBAND</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/beatles-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="BEATLES - YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)" title="BEATLES - YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039">BEATLES</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/602567572039">YELLOW SUBMARINE (PIC DISC)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] Limited edition 7-inch vinyl picture disc now available!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>

          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0619/clutch-250x250.JPG" 
            alt="CLUTCH - HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)" title="CLUTCH - HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842">CLUTCH</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/896308002842">HOW TO SHAKE HANDS (PIC DISC)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] Picture disc now available!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
              
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/devil-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="DEVILDRIVER - OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1" title="DEVILDRIVER - OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126">DEVILDRIVER</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/840588116126">OUTLAWS TIL THE END V.1</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/townsend-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="DEVIN TOWNSEND - OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV" title="DEVIN TOWNSEND - OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026">DEVIN TOWNSEND</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758510026">OCEAN MACHINE: LIVE AT ANCIENT ROMAN THEATRE PLOVDIV</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>

     </tr>

      <tr>   
         <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/goldfrapp-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="GOLDFRAPP - SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)" title="GOLDFRAPP - SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523">GOLDFRAPP</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/724596973523">SILVER EYE (2CD/DELUXE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/immortal-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)" title="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225">IMMORTAL</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361445225">NORTHERN CHAOS GODS (WHITE/BLACK)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Indie exclusive black and white colored vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
               
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/immortal-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS" title="IMMORTAL - NORTHERN CHAOS GODS" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021">IMMORTAL</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/727361322021">NORTHERN CHAOS GODS</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/marr-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="JOHNNY MARR - CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)" title="JOHNNY MARR - CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600">JOHNNY MARR</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190296955600">CALL THE COMET (PURPLE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Indie exclusive purple vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/lucifer-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="LUCIFER - LUCIFER II" title="LUCIFER - LUCIFER II" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728">LUCIFER</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/190758588728">LUCIFER II</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/perfect-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="PERFECT CIRCLE - EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)" title="PERFECT CIRCLE - EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102">PERFECT CIRCLE</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/405053840102">EAT THE ELEPHANT (RED/BLUE)</a></h4>
              <p>[ LP ] Red and blue vinyl LP pressing!</p>
            </div>
          </td>
     </tr>
    
     <tr>
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/murphy-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="PETER MURPHY - 5 ALBUMS" title="PETER MURPHY - 5 ALBUMS" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523">PETER MURPHY</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/607618211523">5 ALBUMS</a></h4>
              <p>[ CD ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   
          <td width="25%" style="font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px;" align="center" valign="top">
            <div class="image"><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558"><img src="http://vvinyl.com/shop/image/cache/catalog/2018/0703/tiger-250x250.jpg" 
            alt="TIGER ARMY - DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)" title="TIGER ARMY - DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div class="caption">
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558">TIGER ARMY</a></h4>
              <h4><a href="http://vvinyl.com/shop/4050538388558">DARK PARADISE (COLORED VINYL W/DL)</a></h4>
              <p>[ New 7 inch Vinyl ] </p>
            </div>
          </td>
                                   

      
      
   </tr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you! will this also make the images responsive as well? As the newsletter will be seen on both laptops and phones.

Comment: As long as only percentage values are used (also for the table elements), it will be responsive, yes.